# How to pick the right digital certificate to code-sign executables under Windows?

Tags: windows, certificate, code-signing, digital-certificate

I need to get a digital certificate to sign my EXEs, DLLs, screensavers and MSI files under Windows. I keep finding a host of certs for various prices.

Here's just a few (for August 2012):

- [VeriSign](https://www.symantec.com/verisign/code-signing/microsoft-authenticode) for $499/yr.
- [Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/code-signing/index.html) for $299/yr.
- [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/code-signing-certificate.aspx) for $199/yr.
- [Comodo](http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/?key5sk1=d7ea482f69ef0152f4148711dc474fbbe791c754&key5sk2=&key5sk3=1343706861000&key5sk4=&key5sk5=1343706871000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=CH200113247&key6sk3=7&key6sk4=en-us&key6sk5=US&key6sk6=0&key6sk7=Google&key6sk8=113300&key6sk9=16801050&key6sk10=true&key6sk11=2816657e20dca66aeba335cbaa3aa5bc53588794&key6sk12=2032&key7sk1=124&key1sk1=ors&key1sk2=Google) for $180/yr.

So can someone explain why is there such a big price difference? Maybe someone who actually dealt with digital certs -- if you can share any possible pitfalls?

Comment: Make sure to ask for discounts, especially when you purchase a certificate with a longer validity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Comodo for our code-signing, and we get our certificate through a reseller which makes them cheaper still.  We've signed all our products with them, and distributed them to many clients, and have yet to see any problems at all.  I don't see any reason to use the more expensive providers.

---

EDIT: One thing I just thought of - if you intend to enrol in Microsofts WinQual program, I think they have very specific requirements for codesigning certificates, which I think would limit your choice of providers.  I'd read up on the subject if that affects you.

Comment: The reseller we use is [ksoftware](http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/) (no relation but a satisfied customer)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Does it make a difference what country you're located in?

Comment: It also seems like they have some issue with Google Chrome. I loaded up your page in Chrome and it showed a strange warning in red. Any idea what is that about?

Comment: I don't think the country makes any difference.  It's a global market, though all the big CAs are based in the US.  We're in the UK, fwiw.  So far as the Chrome thing goes, the warning seems to suggest Firefox is a better browser for collecting certificates; I seem to remember they recommended Firefox last time we renewed our certificate, which we did, and we didn't have any trouble. I don't know enough about the subject to understand what makes Firefox better for that I'm afraid

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up info. I am in US so I'm glad to hear that it worked in UK. I'm also assuming that you use these certs to sign your Windows executable files, right?

Comment: That's correct, we use Microsoft signtool to sign .exe and .msi files

Answer (score 3):

Verisign's code signing certificates are usable for signing kernel-mode drivers (GlobalSign is the only alternative for this goal with lower prices). The rest is the same from technical point of view. Different CAs use different customer validation techniques and require different sets of documents. If you are a company and have an office, you should not have problems with any CA. If you have only a virtual office or you are a one-man business, than requirements of some CAs can be harder to meet than requirements of other different CAs.

Comment: One follow-up question. Can I use Microsoft's signtool with all of these certificates, or do I need to use some of their own proprietary signing tool?

Comment: signtool can be used with any of those certificates - the format of certificates is uniform. You might need to do some conversion or certificate installation to Windows Certificate storage but this is irrelevant of CA and depends on the tools (eg. signtool requires the certificate to be in Widows cert.storage for kernel-mode signing).